# what is an abstract button?

Tags: java, button

i'm learning about Swing in java and it states that a lot of the buttons inherit from abstract button, i'm not sure what this means. Do I ever have to implement or extend this ever and what is the purpose of the abstract button?

Comment: See [AbstractButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html) which says "Defines common behaviors for buttons and menu items". Of course, the tutorials/documentation would have *said/hinted* this was a name of a class, which is easily searchable .. (I used `javadoc 7 button` followed by Ctrl+F in the first link.)

Comment: thanks for restating what already confuses me. why do they inherit from that class rather than being able to do it themselves?

Comment: Abstract classes are - for better or worse - the primary approach in Java for sharing implementation. Having to write the *same code* again and again gets really tiresome and is error-prone. Interfaces can only define contracts while Abstract classes can contain [partial] implementations - and there are *plenty* of existing questions/answers on stackoverflow that cover the reasoning/goals, [ab]use, and limitations of Abstract classes.

Answer (score 3):

The abstract button is a framework-provided class that implements some, but not all, behaviors of a button. Most likely, you won't ever have to extend it.

For the record, "extending" and "creating a subclass" is the same thing. As for "implementing", in Java, the term is used for implementing an *interface*.

Comment: thank you, so it's purpose is to provide more flexibility and function with buttons?

Comment: @Jay - and also to implement common behaviour in one place; see the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

The abstract button class defines common behaviors for buttons and menu items in swings.

Comment: i've read that, i just don't understand: why can't the buttons implement this themselves?

Comment: @Jay - they could, but then you'd have copies of virtually identical methods in each of the button classes.  That would be a BAD IDEA.

Comment: @StephenC, I do see where it can be confusing for new programmers in that AbstractButton itself doesn't contain any abstract methods; There's literally no contract requirement to fulfill.  You simply cannot instantiate it _as is_ without extending it (and adding nothing).  In this way, it's a far cleaner mechanism than simply supplying a "crummy" non-abstract button for others to extend, and a clear message to the engineer of what you pointed out: This class is for only for commonality among all like minded descendants.

Comment: If they are confused by that, that's a misunderstand of what a Java `abstract` class really is.